# Is there a point to the Goal Game?

Tags: kirby-return-to-dreamland

In Kirby's Return to Dreamland, you get to play a "Goal Game" at the end of each level. For world 1 at least, this is a game where you jump into layers of clouds using a slingshot/trampoline type thing. I never manage to get very high. Is there a point to this minigame? Is there something at the top of the clouds that I am just not getting to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really.  It's just another chance for you to get some extra stars and possibly an extra life.  Here's how much you get at each level:

1. 30 stars
2. 15 stars
3. 10 stars
4. 5 stars
5. 3 stars
6. 1 star
7. No bonus

Note you don't actually get an extra life reaching the top (like you do in the original Kirby game), you just have to rely on getting 100 stars for that.

If you're playing cooperatively with multiple players and you all land on the same level, you get (at least) twice the amount of stars if you were alone.  e.g., two players both land on the first level, you get a total of 30 stars.  Otherwise you get the amount of stars of whomever got to the highest level.  I can't say for sure if you get triple or quadruple for more than two players, I haven't played with more than two.

Comment: I'm not sure about the other levels, but getting three players on the top level grants three 1-UPs instead of stars.

Comment: With 2 players, the top level will give 2 1ups as well. It's both of you hitting the *second* level that you'll get 60 stars - twice the normal amount of 15 each.